# How to draw line with Microsoft POS Printer

Tags: pos

I am using the Microsoft Point Of Service SDK and I am testing both in my application and the Sample provided with the SDK to try and print a Line with code similar to this:

```
posPrinter.DrawRuledLine(PrinterStation.Receipt, "0,500", LineDirection.Horizontal, 1, LineStyle.BrokenLine, 1);
```

I get this error:

> POSControlException ErrorCode(Illegal) ExtendedErrorCode(0) occurred: Method DrawRuledLine threw an exception.  Attempt was made to perform an illegal or unsupported operation with the device, or an invalid parameter value was used.

Microsoft POS has a tendency to throw very generic errors and I don't know what I am doing wrong. I had similar errors on other methods and it turned out it was because I was passing a parameter that didn't quite work, like a too big a width. But I have tested all kinds of combinations and this always fails. And there is no enough documentation on the parameters it receives.

What parameters do I need to pass to this method to draw a line? Is this the preferred way to draw a line with Microsoft POS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Point Of Service(part of the UnifiedPOS implementation) is an API with an abstract standard specification and does not have all the features of a real printer.

If your printer and the service object that runs it do not have DrawRuledLine functionality, you will get that error.

[ErrorCode Enumeration (POS for .NET v1.12 SDK Documentation)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ms884224(v=winembedded.11))

> Illegal
> An attempt was made to perform an illegal or unsupported operation with the device, or an invalid parameter value was used.

The presence or absence of the function can be confirmed in advance by checking the value of the CapRecRuledLine(CapSlpRuledLine for Slip stations) property.

If you want to draw a line on a receipt with this DrawRuledLine method, you need to switch to a printer and service object that supports that feature.

If you don't want to change the printer, you'll have to replace it with a character line.

Comment: I am pretty new with POS, sorry for the silly question but when you say a character line is just print a text line using a character, right? Thanks a lot for that CapRecRuledLIne tip, I will check it out. Is there a documentation for those methods?

Comment: Btw I contemplated the possibility it wasn't supported, but the problem is that it throws that same error if you use the methods wrong and I have limited access to the computer with the printer. Locally I can use only a Simulator and those methods are not implemented in the simulator.

Comment: You can download the [UnifiedPOS specifications here](https://www.omg.org/retail/unified-pos.htm). Then .NET usually uses exceptions instead of return values to signal errors, so you don't have to worry too much about it. Think of it as just an error notification and deal with it.

Comment: You are awesome, this was very helpful. I am trying to finish a work another developer that left started and I don't even know what to read/research at times.